# Searchable Activity com Recycler View

Tags: android

Possuo uma Searchable Activity que está sendo utilizada em duas activitys diferentes, porém no resultado que gera uma Recycler View gostaria de tratar o click, para saber qual foi a Activity geradora. Só que ao utilizar o método getLocalClassName() dentro do adapter, ele sempre me retorna o nome da Searchable Activity.

Existe alguma outra forma de saber qual a activity geradora (antes da searchable)?

Seguem os códigos utilizados.

Menu da activity CriarPedidoActivity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_criar_pedido, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView;
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchable_activity);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    } else {
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    }
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    return true;
}
```

Searchable Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable_clientes);

    // TOOLBAR
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarClientes);
    mToolbar.setTitle("Resultado de pesquisa - Clientes");
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);
    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    clContainer = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl_container);

    hendleSearch(getIntent());
}

public void hendleSearch(Intent intent) {
    intent.getComponent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
        String q = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        filtroClientes(q);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView txtRazaoSocial;
    public TextView txtEndereco;
    public TextView txtBairro;
    public TextView txtCidade;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        txtRazaoSocial = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRazaoSocial);
        txtEndereco = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEndereco);
        txtBairro = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBairro);
        txtCidade = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCidade);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clientesActivity.getLocalClassName().equals("activity.CriarPedidoActivity")) {
            Cliente clienteSelecionado = mDataset.get(getPosition());
            PedidoCabecalho pedidoCabecalho = new PedidoCabecalho();
            pedidoCabecalho.setCliente(clienteSelecionado);
            Intent irParaPedidoItem = new Intent(clientesActivity, CriarPedidoItemActivity.class);
            irParaPedidoItem.putExtra(CLIENTE_SEELECIONADO, pedidoCabecalho);
            clientesActivity.startActivity(irParaPedidoItem);
        } else {
            Cliente clienteSelecionado = mDataset.get(getPosition());
            Intent irParaDetalhesCliente = new Intent(clientesActivity, DetalheClienteActivity.class);
            irParaDetalhesCliente.putExtra(CLIENTE_SEELECIONADO, clienteSelecionado);
            clientesActivity.startActivity(irParaDetalhesCliente);
        }
    }
}
```